# Is there a way to access python code from third party kodi/xbmc plugins in your plugin?

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I have experience with python, but I just got started learning how to develop addons for Kodi.  Having a bit of trouble understanding the docs.

**Is it possible to import or otherwise access python code from another plugin or script?**

For example if my addon was: `script.hello.world` and i wanted to use `some_method` from `plugin.video.someplugin`.

addon.xml imports the plugin i wish to access:

```
<requires>
    <import addon="xbmc.python" version="2.14.0"/>
    <import addon="plugin.video.plexbmc" version="3.4.5" optional="true"/>
</requires>
```

I was fairly sure this would not work, and i was correct:

```
from plugin.video.someplugin.default import some_method
```

The only thing in the docs that looked like it might work was this:

```
spi = xbmcaddon.Addon ('plugin.video.someplugin')
```

I can access the xbmc's built in methods of spi, but no way to get to the actual python objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! Simply add the desired directory to the system's python path:

```
spi = xbmcaddon.Addon ('plugin.video.someplugin')
path = spi.getAddonInfo('path')
sys.path.append (xbmc.translatePath( os.path.join( path) ))
from default import some_method
some_method()
```